# Create a query that return results unique by combination of keys

Tags: mongodb

I have these documents:

```
{a: 1, b:1, c:1}
{a: 1, b:2, c:1}
{a: 1, b:1, c:2}
```

I need as result something filter by something similar to

```
 _.uniqBy(documents, d => d.a + d.b);
```

so therefore the result should be

```
{a: 1, b:1, c:1}
{a: 1, b:2, c:1}
```

I want to do filter through mongodb itself and do not later for two reasons:

- I use the `skip` property, if I filter the labels by my own then I have to add to the skip property the same amount of duplicates I removed. Since  the function can be called with different skip values, I'd have to recalculate how many documents I removed because duplicated, and it would be computational too expensive
- I want to use the same query to do a `model.count()`

I do not want to modify data, because I have also something like `model.find({c:2})`. The data are not **real** duplicates, but I need to consider them as duplicated for some tasks

Comment: Are you trying to `skip` douments in each unique combination of keys ? Or just of the final output. [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) does the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query using `$group` and `$project`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group : {
        _id : { a : "$a" , b :  "$b" } , 
        count: { $sum : 1 },
        c : {$first : "$c"}}},
     {$project : {"_id" : 0, a: "$_id.a",  b : "$_id.b", "c" : 1}}   
    ]);
```

**Output:-**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "c" : 1,
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "c" : 1,
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 1
}
```

**Approach 2:-**

This query will give the count of different values of "C"s and number of "C"s skipped.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group : {
        _id : { a : "$a" , b :  "$b" } ,         
        count: { $sum : 1 },
        c : {$first : "$c"}}},
     {$project : {"_id" : 0, a: "$_id.a",  b : "$_id.b", "c" : 1, 
         "numberOfCSkipped" : {$cond: {if : { $gt : ["$count", 1] }, then : {$subtract: ["$count", 1]}, else : 0 }},
         "numberOfDifferentCs" : "$count" }}   
    ]);
```

**numberOfCSkipped** - zero means no duplicates i.e. only one "C" for the "a" and "b" combination

**numberOfDifferentCs** - count of different values of "C"s for "a" and "b" combination

**Output:-**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "c" : 1,
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "numberOfCSkipped" : 0,
    "numberOfDifferentCs" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "c" : 1,
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 1,
    "numberOfCSkipped" : 1,
    "numberOfDifferentCs" : 2
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thanks - there is any way I can use the `skip` option as in `find()` (or something equivalent)?

Comment: Not sure what you would like to achieve with skip. I have added another approach to get the count of C attributes. Hope it is helpful.